# How to use the Firebase objects in different files?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

This might be a stupid question but I am learning all of this by myself and I didn't find anything about it in the documentation.

I am currently building a Vue app and using Firebase as my backend. In order to use the Firebase services, you create an `app` object with the `initializeApp()` method and then access services like the database by calling `getDatabase(app)` and working with the returned object. Now my question is: If I do these things inside my top level component (App), but then need to access the database inside another component, can I just call the `getDatabase()` method again, or do I have to somehow export the first object so that I can access it from other files?

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase SDKs are pretty good at re-using objects behind the scenes, so you can typically call `initializeApp` once and then call `getDatabase` in each component.

Comment: Can I just follow up with another question I have? I noticed that in the docs, sometimes the `getDatabase()` method is called with the `app` object, and sometimes without any arguments. Is there a difference?

Comment: There is always one default app. Calling `getDatabase` without a parameter gives you the database for that default app. If you pass a parameter, it gives the database for *that* app/